# Failed connections between docker containers

Tags: java, sockets, docker, tcp, docker-compose

My application consists of a standalone java server, a client java web start application, a set of webapps that all run in one wildfly instance, and postgres.

The client container is just an nginx server that serves a JNLP and corresponding java client.

All of my containers are running on the same host.

Here's a slightly stripped down version of my dockerfile:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    privileged: true
    image: <server_image>
    networks:
    - myapp

  client:
    image: <client_image>
    networks:
    - myapp

  webapp:
    privileged: true
    image: <wildfly_image>
    networks:
    - myapp

  postgres:
    image: <postgres_image>
    volumes:
    - /pgdata:/pgdata
    networks:
    - myapp

  lb:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy:latest
    environment:
    - FORCE_DEFAULT_BACKEND=False
    - ADDITIONAL_BACKEND_WEBAPPS=server webapp1 webapp:8080
    - ADDITIONAL_BACKEND_CLIENT=server client1 client:80
    - ADDITIONAL_BACKEND_SERVER=mode tcp,server server1 server:8080
    - EXTRA_FRONTEND_SETTINGS_443=acl url_xmlrpc path_beg /xmlrpc, \
        acl url_api path_beg /api, \
        acl url_sys_api path_beg /sys-api, \
        acl url_dashboard path_beg /dashboard-app, \
        acl url_client path_beg /, \
        use_backend WEBAPPS if url_xmlrpc, \
        use_backend WEBAPPS if url_api, \
        use_backend WEBAPPS if url_sys_api, \
        use_backend WEBAPPS if url_dashboard, \
        use_backend CLIENT if url_client
    - EXTRA_FRONTEND_SETTINGS_8443=mode tcp,use_backend SERVER
    ports:
    - 443:443
    - 8443:8443
    networks:
    - myapp

networks:
  myapp:
    external: false
```

From my pc, I can download the java web start client from the client container, I can load the webapps (in chrome) from the webapp container, and I can connect to the standalone java server. The java server is able to connect to postgres. The webapps are able to load resources from the client container.

Everything works except the wildfly webapp can't establish a TCP socket connection to the standalone java server.

This is running in AWS, and the firewall is wide open. CentOS has been updated completely, and I'm, running Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be with docker-compose version 1.14.0-rc1, build c18a7ad.

I'm running the **exact** same setup in our internal data center and everything works flawlessly.

Does anybody have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: What's is the error that wildfly shows? And, how are you pointing to the standalone java server?

Comment: Marking the network external as false is redundant as that's the default I believe.

Comment: @Robert - Unfortunately, the developers decided to hide the actual exception, so it's been hard to figure out exactly. I'm inclined to believe it's a timeout, though. I've tried connecting to the standalone java server using the docker-compose hostname and port (server:8080), the internal docker IP of the server on port 8080, the URL of the VM on port 8443, the IP address of the VM on port 8443, the docker hostname of the load balancer (lb:8443).

Comment: @johnharris85 - Yeah, I didn't start off with that, but when I was troubleshooting, I came across that as a potential solution. In the end, I liked the specificity.

Comment: I realized I left out a potentially very important detail - we're running this exact same setup in our internal data center and everything works flawlessly. I've updated the question to include that information.

Comment: If the communication does work from the others containers the problem is probably some Java stuff in webapp. The only thing that I see different is the `privileged: true`, but it shouldn't bother the linking.

Comment: Check whether you're running the same images version in your PC versus the data center. Specially compare image ids

Comment: Are you % sure of this? "`wildfly webapp can't establish a TCP socket connection to the standalone java server.`"

Comment: I was able to expose a debugging port and connect to it from eclipse. I'm fairly certain that the TCP socket connection times out. The images are no longer the same because one of my developers added some debugging code for me. But I am certain that they were exactly the same prior to that.

Comment: Hm, maybe there's not actually a socket creation issue. I have a test class that's able to connect from the webapp container to the server container.

Comment: This is all I'm really getting from the webapp:

Exception opening socket: server; 8080: Connection reset. The server; 8080 is printed from the webapp, the Connection reset part is the error message.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, it turns out it was bad coding on the developer's part. We've solved the problem.